# Changing the radius of a border in css on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website builder I have created and I have a div that makes a button for people to use. I want them to be able to change the radius and it show in real time on the screen.

I have other stuff working like font-family, color, font-size and so on. They all work great. But I can't get the radius to change except to 0. It will change from something to 0. But it will not change to say 20px or 30px etc..

Here are the pieces of the code.

The Original CSS to start with:

```
 .button {
    border-radius: <?php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px;
    -moz-border-radius: <?php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px;
    -webkit-border-radius: <?php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    color: #<?php if($r['btntcolor']!='')echo $r['btntcolor'];else echo"FFFFFF";?>;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #<?php if($r['btncolor']!='')echo $r['btncolor'];else echo"00dd10";?>;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: <?php if($r['btntsize']!='')echo $r['btntsize'];else echo"22";?>px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    max-width: 95%;
 }
```

The selection of the radius size:

```
 <SELECT id="btnradius" name="btnradius" class="form-control"
 style="width:90px; font-size:10px;">
 <option value="<?php echo $r['btnradius']?>"> <?php echo $r['btnradius']? </option>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="30">30</option>
 <option value="40">40</option>
 <option value="50">50</option>
 <option value="60">60</option>
 </select>
```

The Code That it should change on the fly:

```
 <div class="button blank4 color_change tcolor_change tsize_change   
 btnradius" style="border-radius: <?php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px; -moz-
 border-radius: <?php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px; -webkit-border-radius: <?
 php echo $r['btnradius'];?>px;" id="btncolor"><?php echo $r['subtext4']?> 
 </div>
```

The script to change the above code on the fly:

```
$('#btnradius').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
$(".btnradius").css("border-radius", valueSelected);
$(".btnradius").css("-moz-border-radius", valueSelected);
$(".btnradius").css("-webkit-border-radius", valueSelected);
 });
```

Comment: No need to repeat three times. `$(".btnradius").css("border-radius", valueSelected +'px');` is quite enough. jQuery will handle vendors out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `px` suffix on your CSS property:

```
$(".btnradius").css("border-radius", valueSelected + "px");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x100pu3/1/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just wonder now how my font-size works lol. I don't have the + "px" on the end and it works great. So my question is, for better coding, should I add the + "px" to my font-size code? Here is that part of it...  `$(".threesize").css("font-size", valueSelected);`

Comment: @RandyThomas to further explain the obvious, `0` is a valid CSS radius value, while `30`(without a unit) is not - that's the reason setting to `0` was "working" ;)

Comment: @RandyThomas that's cause jQuery let's do that and it converts a numeric value to `px`. border-radius instead seems like does not follows the same rules.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue is actually as you have stated.

> But I can't get the radius to change except to 0. It will change from something to 0. But it will not change to say 20px or 30px etc..

Now your JavaScript says

```
$('#btnradius').on('change', function(e) {
  var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
  var valueSelected = this.value; //<-- here is the problem
  $(".btnradius").css("border-radius", valueSelected);
});
```

Note the `this.value` well that will be the value from the `option` selected in your drop down box. Now all the values are missing the `px` from the end of the value.

This can be changed two ways.

1. Change the `value` of the `option` tags to be `#.px` (ie `60px`)
2. Modify the `valueSelected` option to read `var valueSelected = this.value + 'px';`

The reason that `0` works is `0` does not need a unit specifier. However all other values will (ie `px`, `em`, `%`, etc)